# Calling addition function to calculate sum of input parameters

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, calling-convention

I have this set of codes (ASP.NET Web application) which calls an addition function of a java web service.

**RestfulClient.cs**

```
public class RestfulClient
{
    private static HttpClient client;

    internal Task addition(object firstNumber, object secondNumber)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static RestfulClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> addition(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            var endpoint = string.Format("addition/{0}/{1}", firstNumber, secondNumber);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.html");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What codes should i add in my controller to call the addition function? I want user to input two numbers in the URL (When i run my ASP.NET Web API) and i want the ASP.NET Web API to be able to use the addition method which i have called from the java web service to calculate the sum and display it as e.g. `{"firstNumber":9,"secondNumber":6,"sum":15}`.

**AdditionController.cs**

```
public class AdditionController : ApiController
{
    private RestfulClient restfulClient = new RestfulClient();

    public IHttpActionResult Get(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        //What do i have to include here?
        //Tried
        var result = restfulClient.addition(firstNumber, secondNumber); 
        return Json(result);

    }
}
```

I tried some codes however i do not get any output. The page just keeps loading without giving me any outputs.

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "AdditionApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/addition/{firstNumber}/{secondNumber}",
        defaults: new { action = "Get", controller = "Addition" }
        );
    }
}
```

**Addition.java**

```
public class Addition {

private int firstNumber, secondNumber, sum;

public Addition(String firstNumber, String secondNumber) {
    this.firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.trim());
    this.secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.trim());
    updateSum();
  }

public int getFirstNumber() {
    return firstNumber;
  }

public void setFirstNumber(int firstNumber) {
    this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
    updateSum();
  }

public int getSecondNumber() {
    return secondNumber;
  }

public void setSecondNumber(int secondNumber) {
    this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    updateSum();
  }

public int getSum() {
    return sum;
  }

public void updateSum() {
    this.sum = this.firstNumber + this.secondNumber;
  }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Addition [firstNumber=%d, secondNumber=%d, sum=%d%n", //
            firstNumber, secondNumber, sum);
  }
}
```

**AdditionController.java**

```
@RestController
public class AdditionController {

private static final String template = " %s";
private static int getSum;

@RequestMapping("/addition/{param1}/{param2}")
@ResponseBody 

public Addition addition 
            (@PathVariable("param1") int firstNumber,@PathVariable("param2") int secondNumber) {
return new Addition(
        (String.format(template, firstNumber)), String.format(template, secondNumber));
  }
}
```

Someone please help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turns out to be that in the RestfulClient.adition the program get's stuck on the line: var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint); never receives a response. For now a fix could be:

```
public string addition(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                var endpoint = string.Format("addition/{0}/{1}", firstNumber, secondNumber);
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
                //This will check whether or not the response was executed successfully(status code 200ish or not 
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"The server responded with a bad request of type: {response.StatusCode}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.html");
            }
            return null;
        }
```

In case someone got a less work around ish solution to this problem please share.

Comment: How do i go about doing that..? Can you help me to elaborate more please.

Comment: I do not want to input the values in there. I would like it in a way such that i am able to input the values in the URL as parameters

Comment: And i want to use the addition function that i created in the java web service

Comment: Ah, I read your comments a bit late so my post is already a bit outdated. I'm having a standup right now after that I'll fix that.

Comment: Okay quick question. Where does Java actually come in? all the classes you posted first have the .cs extension and not .java.

Second of so if I understand correcly you only want to get the Sum returned and not a whole json string containing the parameters too?

Comment: I will edit and post the java web service codes too. Anything is ok. The whole json string e.g. `{"firstNumber":9,"secondNumber":6,"sum":15}` or just the sum is ok too but i prefer if i am able to return the whole json string.

Comment: I have included my java classes. Please do help me if u are able to

Comment: Ah I guess I was wrong at the start. About the circle reference and stuff. at least as long as you did not switch up the port from the C# local host and the Java REST api in the Restful client class. I'll remove a lot of my previous edit and give it the code so you can debug this better.

Comment: Okay I edited my post again. These changes to your 2 methods should allow you to narrow down the issue. now you've included the .java files it seems like you are good on the way. so I'm just curious to see what kind of error code you will get

Comment: Thought I spotted a mistake but was not. make sure to use if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) and not if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) my excuse

Comment: I did not include the message.box code. I included the rest of the codes. I still face the same error. `Waiting for localhost` :(

Comment: When launching the WebApi from netbeans and navigating to it with chrome/firefox to http://localhost:8080/ does the page say that there was any sort of error or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157976/discussion-between-susmitha-naidu-and-drag0nvil).